# JavaScript promise is not frozen and next line is executed

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a function that returns a promise:

```
const validateForm = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         // code here takes time
         return resolve('valid');
    });
}
```

And I use this promise this way:

```
validateForm()
.then(function(result) {
   console.log('form is valid');
})

console.log('line after promise');
```

I expect to see this output:

> form is valid
> line after promise

But I see this output:

> line after promise
> form is valid

How should I fix this code to get the first result? How freeze the code to not execute lines after promise until promise is either resolved or rejected?

Comment: Add another `.then()`.

Comment: That's not how promises work, they don't "freeze" anything. They're asynchronous

Comment: or use `async`/`await`

Comment: use async/await if you want to  pause and wait for your asynchronous code

Comment: Don't use a promise at all?

Comment: Yes there is nothing intrinsically async about any of your code here. Using promises is essentially pointless. I'm presuming this is some kind of simplification, but if it's not, then just remove the promise.

Answer (score 0):

When using promises, all of the code at a given "level" is run first, then async / promises are run, which may then trigger thens.

```
1 validateForm()
2 .then(function(result) {
3    console.log('form is valid');
4 })
5 
6 console.log('line after promise');
```

In your code, it would essentially go line 1 and 6, then line 2, 3, 4 when the promise resolves.

You are trying to force async code to run synchronously, which just doesn't work. If you want your expected output, everything has to be in a then:

```
validateForm()
.then(function(result) {
   console.log('form is valid');
}).then(function () {
   console.log('line after promise');
});
```

Or it could be in the same then() just on the next line. But it can't just be out there.

Or you could be getting confused by seeing things that use async/await. If you're in an async function, you can do:

```
await validateForm()
.then(function(result) {
   console.log('form is valid');
})
   
console.log('line after promise');
```

Which is basically just syntaxical sugar for the above (though does tend to be people's preference, including mine).

Comment: I can't use `await` keyword, as I'm using old JavaScript without WebPack or any other compiler.

Comment: Then your only option is to chain `then()` or put your next lines in one big `then()`.